# Setting java property for Jenkins -Dgroovy.use.classvalue=true

Tags: java, jenkins

I am using Jenkins version 2.165 and I am having problems with CPU utilisation of Jenkins on my EC2 instance on AWS. One of the solutions I found is to set the java property `-Dgroovy.use.classvalue=true`.

I tried to do it but I could not find where to manage that property, so some help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: what does *to manage that property* exactly means? manage it where?

Comment: I mean where to configure the property to set it to true. That's the thing, I do not know where to do it. I found this solution somewhere but it was not specified where to change it.

Comment: you do have jenkins, do you? You do have configured gradle there, right?